# Minimum/Maximum Distance from a Point to a Sphere Using Questionable Method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, spheres

To find the points on the surface of a sphere with radius $R$, centered at the origin, that are closest/furthest from a given point, $(a,b,c)$, you could use the Lagrange multiplier method to optimize the distance formula $$D(x,y,z)=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}$$ using $$g(x,y,z)={x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2}$$ as the constraint function. You could also solve the problem geometrically, without calculus. However, why can't you combine the two formulas and optimize the resulting function? So, dealing with $D^2$ to not have to deal with the radical:$$D^2(x,y,z)=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2$$$$=x^2+y^2+z^2-2ax-2by-2zc+a^2+b^2+c^2$$ But then, from the equation for a sphere, $z^2=-x^2-y^2+R^2$. Substituting this in,$$D^2(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+(-x^2-y^2+R^2)-2ax-2by-2zc+a^2+b^2+c^2$$$$=R^2-2ax-2by-2zc+a^2+b^2+c^2$$ So, the function reduces down to a linear function of $x,y$ and $z$....This seems fishy. Now if you try to optimize $D^2$ by finding the points where $\nabla D^2=0$, you get that the partial derivatives of the function are constants (aka, never zero unless just by coincidence based on $a,b,$ and $c$). So where are the maximum/minimum values located? What is wrong with this method?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this approach. Yes, you get to optimize a linear function, but only on the sphere. To use Lagrange multiplier, you need the extra term $\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2)$ which will break the linearity of the goal function.

The Lagrange multiplier basically says that on a contrained surface, you don't necessarily have vanishing gradient on points where max/min are achieved, but the gradient has to be perpendicular to the surface (you can grow your function but only beyond the surface). In this particular case, that would mean the gradient $(-2a, -2b, -2c)$ needs to be perp to the sphere, i.e. it has to be parallel to $(x, y, z)$.

Comment: But this approach gives no answer. The gradient of the function to be optimized is never zero based on a point $x,y,z$. So where is the minimum/maximum?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of the Lagrange multiplier method and constrained optimization in general. For example the funciton $f(x,y)=x$ achieves maximum $1$ at $(1,0)$ on the cirlce $x^2+y^2=1$, but at the point $(1,0)$, the $f_x=1\not=0$. I have updated the answer to give some intuition about the Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: But the approach used in the original post has nothing to do with Lagrange multipliers. It tries to turn constrained optimization into unconstrained by creating a new function. Why can't I just find the points where the gradient of that function is zero. There should be two of them: one where the maximum occurs and one where the minimum occurs.

Comment: Because you cannot just forget about the constraint. After all the simplification of your goal function has used the constraint. If you get out of the constraints, then the equivalence of the original function and the linear function you derived won't hold any more. You are not creating a new function but to express it in a different way (only on the constrained area). At the end, you still need Lagrange to solve the seemingly simlified optimization.